# How to install open policy agent on windows?

Tags: open-policy-agent

How to install OPA in windows ? When I double click on exe it says that install using command prompt. But there is no command I found to install OPA.

I want to integrate OPA with Visual Studio code editor, and evaluate policies from VS. I followed steps in https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tsandall.opa but getting empty output while evaluating query as OPA is not installed.

Answer (score 3):

OPA ships as a [self contained executable](https://openpolicyagent.org/downloads/latest/opa_windows_amd64.exe) - there is no need (nor option) to install it, but putting the binary in your `$PATH` will help if commonly run. A bash like shell like [git bash](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-bash) will most likely help even more.